# Joining With No Key - SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please use the code below to help understand my situation. Essenetially I have the first two tables and I want to create table_3 but I do not know how because their is nothing to join on, I do not think a Union is the best call..so I am stuck:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_1` 
(
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_1` (`date`, `first_name`, `last_name`) 
VALUES ('1-1-20', 'John', 'Charlie'),
       ('2-1-20', 'John', 'Jamie'),
       ('3-1-20', 'John', 'Stevie');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_2` 
(
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `new_first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `new_last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_2` (`date`,`new_first_name`, `new_last_name`) 
VALUES ('4-1-20', 'John', 'Fidora'),
       ('5-1-20', 'John','Bowl'),
       ('6-1-20', 'Joe', 'berka');


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_3` 
(
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `new_first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `new_last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);       
  INSERT INTO `table_3` (`date`,`first_name`, `last_name`, `new_first_name`, `new_last_name`) 
VALUES ('1-1-20', 'John', 'Charlie', '',''),
       ('2-1-20', 'John', 'Jamie', '', ''),
       ('3-1-20', 'John', 'Stevie', '', ''),
       ('4-1-20', '', '', 'John', 'Fidora'),
       ('5-1-20', '', '', 'John', 'Bowl'),
       ('6-1-20', '', '', 'Joe', 'Berka');
```

With the two tables above, how can I get to the desired third table?

Comment: Can you be clearer about what your desired outcome is?

Comment: What is the logic by which Jeremy and Jack are being dropped from the expected result set?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - sorry just took those two names out. Weren’t supposed to be in there. And to Mark - respectfully it’s pretty clear. Just how to get to table t3 from table 1 - and table 2. You can copy this code into sql fiddle and see the tables. I can’t really explain it clearer than the code

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want a union query here:

```
SELECT date, first_name, last_name, '' AS new_first_name, '' AS new_last_name FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT date, '', '', new_first_name, new_last_name FROM table_2
ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
 insert into table_3
 select
 nvl(t1.date,t2.date)
 t1.first_name,
 t1.last_name,
 t2.new_first_name,
 t2.new_last_name
 from 
 table_1 t1
 full outer join table_2  t2
 on t1.date = t2.date;
```